# Doctrine: how to get two entities' objects from two tables with different clauses?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

There are two entity classes, I want to fetch their objects from MySQL table within one query:

```
SELECT d, e 
        FROM OrganizerBundle:DailyTask d, OrganizerBundle:Event e
        WHERE d.weekday = 'all' OR DATE_FORMAT(e.date,'%Y-%m-%d') = :date
```

As you see, I need DailyTasks with weekday = 'all' and Events with date = :date. The problem is - WHERE works only for first table (weekday = 'all') + I get all objects from second table. How to separate WHERE clauses for two entities?

Comment: Change your OR to an AND for starters.

Comment: @Jason, logically, it gives no results for the query

Comment: Does DailyTask have an association with Event?  If so you should use a JOIN for them.

Comment: NO, these are absolutely different classes/objects.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Why are you not fetching them with two queries?

Comment: I know that I can use second query but this way will be more logical(I need all these objects to build one table) and optimized

Comment: Just want to know how is it possible to use two clauses here

Comment: `UNION` isn't supported in Doctrine, so you could do it using NativeSql and then ResultSetMapping, but that's overcomplicated.  You're doing something a bit unnatural, so I would just grab them separately with two queries and then merge as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, within Doctrine 2 what you want is not possible.

You state that you want to build one table from this data. I would suggest using native SQL, and use MySQL's powerful `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`.

I have no idea what your table structure is, both of your new table and your old tables, so I'm just guessing that a `UNION` could help you put this in a single query, but otherwise simply use two different inserts.

Note that `UNION` is mostly neat when two tables have a similar structure. I'm guessing from your entity names that Events and DailyTasks both have a date and some other common fields.

You'd get something like this:

`$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO newtable (date, description)
                SELECT date, description FROM 
                    (SELECT date, description FROM dailytask WHERE weekday = 'all') 
                    UNION 
                    (SELECT date, description FROM event WHERE DATE_FORMAT(e.date,'%Y-%m-%d') = ?)";
    $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();`